# MySQL -- How to do this better?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
$activeQuery = mysql_query("SELECT count(`status`) AS `active` FROM `assignments` WHERE `user` = $user_id AND `status` = 0");
$active = mysql_fetch_assoc($activeQuery);

$failedQuery = mysql_query("SELECT count(`status`) AS `failed` FROM `assignments` WHERE `user` = $user_id AND `status` = 1");
$failed = mysql_fetch_assoc($failedQuery);

$completedQuery = mysql_query("SELECT count(`status`) AS `completed` FROM `assignments` WHERE `user` = $user_id AND `status` = 2");
$completed = mysql_fetch_assoc($completedQuery);
```

There has to be a better way to do that, right? I don't know how much I need to elaborate as you can see what I'm trying to do, but is there any way to do all of that in one query? I need to be able to output the active, failed, and completed assignments, preferably in one query.

Comment: *(reference)* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I'm not taking any user input, though.

Comment: Depends on how you're getting $user_id. It's not coming straight from a cookie, is it?

Comment: $user_id is the ID that's associated with the row in the users table that matches up with their username/pass that they use to log in. I use mysql_real_escape_string() on the username and pass, and all other user input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try something like this query

```
SELECT Status , COUNT(*) StatusCount 
FROM assignments
WHERE Status IN (0, 1, 2)
AND User = $user_id 
GROUP BY Status
```

Comment: +1 This is better than my solution in that it selects only the 3 statuses you stated in your question. I had assumed there were only the 3.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$activeQuery = SELECT status, count(status) as "status count" FROM `assignments` WHERE `user` = $user_id GROUP BY `status`
```

edit: added group by

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing them individually you could use the following single SQL statement

```
SELECT count(*), `status` 
FROM `assignments` 
WHERE `user` = $user_id
  AND `status` in (0,1,2)
GROUP BY `status`
ORDER BY `status`
```

The loop around the result set to extract the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GROUP BY` to get it in one query, but on separate rows.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `status`, count(*) AS `num` FROM `assignments` WHERE `user` = $user_id AND `status` in (0,1,2) GROUP BY `status` ORDER BY `status` ASC");
$active_count = 0;
$failed_count = 0;
$completed_count = 0;
while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if ($array['status'] == 0)
        $active_count = $array['num'];
    else if ($array['status'] == 1)
        $failed_count = $array['num'];
    else if ($array['status'] == 2)
        $completed_count = $array['num'];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. For example, if there are no status = 1 records, the failed_count will get the status = 2 value and the completed_count (depending on error_report setting) either be null or cause an error since $completed_array returned from mysql_fetch_assoc will be a boolean false, not an array.

Comment: Good point - that's what I get for answering in a hurry.  How about this new version?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `assignments` WHERE `user` = $user_id AND `status` = 0) AS active,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `assignments` WHERE `user` = $user_id AND `status` = 1) AS failed,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `assignments` WHERE `user` = $user_id AND `status` = 2) AS completed,
FROM `assignments`
GROUP BY active, failed, completed
```

Haven't checked the markup, but this is near or near enough.

Answer (score 0):

When I have the option, I'm in the habit of using prepared statement(s) to help protect against sql-injection protection and for efficiency [(requires using mysqli)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

But if this is not an option, then

```
SELECT
  CASE `status`
      WHEN 0 THEN `active`
      WHEN 1 THEN `failed`
      WHEN 2 THEN `completed`
      ELSE `unknown`
    END
    AS `statuslabel`,
  COUNT(status)
    AS `statuscount`
FROM `assignments` 
WHERE `user` = $escaped_user_id
GROUP BY `statuslabel`
ORDER BY `statuslabel`
```

Note the use of the [$escaped_user_id](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php), which would be created beforehand:

```
$escaped_user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
```